# Why does nobody use Hopfield nets for MNIST?

Tags: machine-learning

I am currently tinkering with Hopfield nets, which is a quite interesting neuron network. I am also writing my own code for Hopfield nets to identify MNIST digits, but it doesn't work correctly, so I tried to search it online. Astonishingly, I barely found anything related to MNIST digits and Hopfield nets. Can anybody tell me the reason？

Answer (score 7):

As far as I understand it, Hopfield networks are good for getting similar results to a given input (content-addressable memory). They are not directly applicable for classification. So you would need a classifier (e.g. an MLP / k-NN) after the Hopfield network anyway. Which is probably the reason why it isn't used.

Also, for MNIST the bar is relatively high. The lowest error is at about 0.23% ([source](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)). Publishing results which are (much) worse than state of the art is difficult and there is basically no incentive to do so. Or even to try if you're not doing something completely new / if you can't expect to be much better.

For people comming here to learn about Hopfield networks: J. J. Hopfield. [Neural networks and physical systems with emergent collective computational abilities](http://www.pnas.org/content/79/8/2554.full.pdf) in Proceedings of the national academy of sciences, 1982.

For Germans: My [German mini-summary of Hopfield neworks](https://martin-thoma.com/neuronale-netze-vorlesung/#ref-hop82-anchor).